# How do you save an Excel HTML text file to an Excel xls binary file?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, export-to-excel, excel-2003, vba

This is one of the questions that is asked alot, but the text to binary mechanism is left out in the question and the answer.  If you export to html from excel it is an Excel html file. Is there a tool that can be used for automation purposes to then take this html excel file and convert it back into an Excel .xls **binary** file? (Note: Binary is a requirement.)  Also is it possible in both 2003 and 2007 or greater?

The reason I ask it this way is because there is a little known secret: You can save an Excel html file as .xls.  Which is not what I am looking for.  I'm trying to find the elusive "Holy Grail" answer to convert an excel html (which is bound to an excel html schema) to binary .xls file.

The business pursose is becase an excel binary file will be much smaller and load much faster than its HTML counterpart especially when file sizes get into the 10Megabyte range and greater.

Comment: How does your method compare with an `.xlsx` file in terms of loading time and size?  Sounds like you're putting yourself through a lot for very little gain.

Comment: Open html file in Excel, save as xls file. Are you having a specific problem with doing that? How are you wanting to automate the process?

Comment: It has to be automated, doing it manually does work, unfortunately it must be automated.

Comment: The xlsx file type is compatible with excel 2007 and above. But there are users that have older versions of excel and the requirement is to stick with a Excel 2003 standard.   I've tried to use excelcnv, but it does not work.  There is also one in Sourceforge but doesn't work with html to xls binary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In VBA:

```
Sub Tester()

      Const FOLDER_PATH As String = "C:\path\to\files\"
      Dim wb As Workbook
      Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FOLDER_PATH & "NoName.html")
      wb.SaveAs Filename:=FOLDER_PATH & "NoName.xls", FileFormat:=xlExcel8

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, short and simple, tested perfectly.  The only question I have now is exception handling for a bad html file.

Comment: How would you define a "bad" html file?

Comment: One that it can't convert to an xls file.